# Где формируется HTML комментариев Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу найти файл, в котором формируется HTML комментариев Wordpress.

Вывожу комментарии следующим образом:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments();?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

на выходе получаю такой HTML внутри `ol`:

```
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 parent" id="comment-8">
    <div id="div-comment-8" class="comment-body">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <cite class="fn">admin</cite><span class="says">says:</span> </div>

        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="#comment-8">
                10.08.2018 в 15:02</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="comment-edit-link" href="#">(Edit)</a> </div>

        <p>Текст комментария</p>

        <div class="reply"><a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm( &quot;div-comment-8&quot;, &quot;8&quot;, &quot;respond&quot;, &quot;78&quot; )" aria-label="Reply to admin">Reply</a></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Я хочу, например, изменить это место `<span class="says">says:</span>`, чтобы тут был не `span` а `div`, к примеру.

Где найти отвечающий за это файл?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments
1 ссылка в гугле

Comment: Вам нужно изменить форму или вид комментария?